# loading spinner with image_picker_web (FLUTTER-WEB)

Tags: flutter, spinner, flutter-web, imagepicker

How can I incorporate a loading spinner in a image_picker_web application that **only triggers as an image is selected**?

The best I have been able to do is a spinner triggered by the 'select image' button, as below, but this shows a spinner when the the directory is opened i.e. before anything is selected, I need it to trigger when the user selects an image and hits 'open' in the directory.

```
Image pickedImage;
bool isWaiting = false;

  pickImage() async {

setState(() {
  isWaiting = true;
});

Image fromPicker =
    await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.widget);

if (fromPicker != null) {

  setState(() {
    isWaiting = false;
    pickedImage = fromPicker;
  });

}
```

}

```
 RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => pickImage(),
              child: isWaiting
                  ? SizedBox(child: Image.asset('assets/spinner.gif'))
                  : Text('Select Image'),
            ),
```

(adapted from the original example: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web/example)

Comment: This code isn't working? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: this is the original example from image_picker_web: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web/example, i just want to include a loading spinner while the image loads

Comment: Okay got it. So what issue are you facing?

Comment: I dont know where to begin - I cant find any examples where a loading spinner is used??

Comment: You can use [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html)

Comment: my problem isn't what spinner to use, but how to trigger it at the right time i.e. when the image is selected, not when the button is pressed

Comment: The above example does that already, isn't it?

Comment: the example triggers from the raisedbutton - that is my problem - how can i trigger it only when the user chooses a file , not before

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the default material [`CircularProgressIndicator()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html), if you want.
2. If you want it a little more colorful with google color accents, you can go with my [`ColoredCircularProgressIndicator()`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colored_progress_indicators) package.
3. If you want a custom spinner then you have to definitely go with this awesome package - [flutter_spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit)

Your implementation is correct, you can also use `GestureDetector` with `Material` widget for input button customizations.

**EDIT -**

As mentioned in comment, if you want the spinner to kick-in AFTER the image is picked, you can use `then()` from `getImage's future` and a void callback to achieve this.

```dart
Image fromPicker = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(outputType: ImageType.widget).then(() => /* do something after image is picked (change widget to spinner in setState) */ );
```

I really don't know why you want to kick-in the spinner AFTER not before.

Also, `image_picker_web` package is now deprecated so use the [`image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package with web check.

Comment: maybe i haven't explained my problem very well - in my example i get a spinner when the button is pressed but i want it to do nothing at all when the button is pressed (except display the available files) . Only when the user chooses the image file do i want the spinner to kick in